# Use Linq to get values

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am using [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

I have created a `JArray` and parsing the id values from it like so -

```
JArray userData = JArray.Parse(response.Content);

foreach (JObject content in userData.Children<JObject>())
{
        items.Add(content["id"].ToString()); 
}
```

However I was trying to also do this usig Linq -

```
var items = userData.Where(x => x["id"].ToString() != null).ToList();
```

This seems to be a faster way to do this, however the problem I am having is that using the first method only adds the id values as I wanted, the Linq option puts the entire data set into items when the condition is met.

How an I change my condition so that it only extracts the id values?

Comment: What is the `response.Content`. Can you show it? :)

Comment: And you deleted your question on sorting as I posted an answer. Oh well your loss.

Comment: @epascarello my apologies I felt it was perhaps a poorly constructed question, I have since enabled it again if this suffices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you actually want LINQ [**`Select`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx).

It allows you to get items by projecting each element of a sequence into a new form.

```
var items = userData.Select(x => x["id"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: I can accept this answer in 11 minutes :/ sorry that was my lack of knowledge of linq for this, spot on answer will accept when I can.